# strange behaviour of strings command

Tags: shell, pipe, output

I am trying to capture mysql traffic and pass those traffic to strings command as follows:

```
tcpdump -i any -s 0 -l -w - dst port 3306 | strings
```

This is working as expected and printing all mysql queries like

```
select * from mytables
show databases
```

But when i am trying to redirect the output to a file, its not printing the output to `/tmp/out` file:

```
tcpdump -i any -s 0 -l -w - dst port 3306 | strings > /tmp/out
```

Can someone explain me the behaviour of above command and why it is not redirecting the output to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution:

Actually strings command is buffering. I disabled the buffering by using

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 command
```

So after changing the whole command to the following, output started going to /tmp/final file.

```
tcpdump -i any -s 0 -l -w - dst port 3306 | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 strings > /tmp/final
```

#### References

- [stdbuf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf)
- [buffering in standard streams](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)
- [linux stdbuf - line-buffered stdin option does not exist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43864/linux-stdbuf-line-buffered-stdin-option-does-not-exist)

Comment: Note that you only need `-o0`, since you're only redirecting stdout (and `-i0` doesn't do anything useful anyway).